# Setup CAPTCHA in Content Types

Tags: 7, captcha

i have configured [captcha](http://drupal.org/project/captcha) module in my drupal 7 site.. but can't understand how to show a captcha in content type, so that while adding content user will have to complete the captcha.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check README.txt of the [captcha](http://drupal.org/project/captcha) module.

> The configuration page is at admin/config/people/captcha,
>   where you can configure the CAPTCHA
>   module   and enable challenges for the desired forms.   You can also
>   tweak the image CAPTCHA to your liking.

1. Go to the configuration page - **admin/config/people/captcha**
2. Select the **Default challenge type** - Math or Image
3. In the form list, you can define which form has CAPTCHA, for example
   if you want to have it on the register form, select a challenge type
   (Math or Image) for the FORM_ID **user_register_form**

If you want to add CAPTCHA to a content type, for example, **blog**, add a new FORM_ID "**blog_node_form**" and click "Save Configuration".

By default, you will not see CAPTCHA on each form when you logged in as administrator, but you can change the option in the configuration page.