# CAPTCHA default for Blog post forms does not work in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, captcha

I'm trying to get CAPTCHA to be automatically added to my blog post forms so that I don't have to enable it individually on each blog post. I've followed the suggestion on [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50628/setup-captcha-in-content-types), but unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. I've enabled everything that I should, but the CAPTCHA doesn't work for blog posts unless I manually enable them per post. This is not practical. I've used the CAPTCHA module fairly extensively before, so I understand how it works, but it's just not doing what I've told it to do.

Does anyone know what may be keeping my site from enabling CAPTCHA as the default for blog posts?

Comment: Do you want to add the captcha to the content type or the comment form of the content type?

Comment: I would like it on the comment form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [same post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50628/setup-captcha-in-content-types) you saw, this time use "**comment_node_blog_form**" as your form id, or "comment_node_CONTENT_TYPE_form" if your content type is not called blog